# Why am I seeing this? "Fatal error: Call to a member function [functionName()] "

Tags: modx-revolution

I have a function and I create a snippet in modx revolution:

```
function functionName(){
    //code here
}
```

I got this fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function functionName()
```

Can anyone tell me how to create functions in snippets in modx revolution?

Comment: Could you explain a little more about the function and where you use it? What version of MODX Revolution are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of effort i get one solution that in Modex now using totaly oops , so directly use function call in page not work , so create Class and put function and then create object and call and it work..:)

```
     Class ClassName{
         function functionName() {  //code here  }
    }
    var myobj = new ClassName();
    myobj->functionName() //it work
```